# Do disjoint cycles commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

When a given set is finite it is clear. I'm asking the general case.

Let $X$ is an arbitrary set.

Let $\sigma,\tau$ be disjoint cycles on $X$.

Then do they commute?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Disjoint cycles always commute. Ask yourself this- what happens when you try to compose the two cycles? You can't simplify them further regardless of the order in which you compose them. Hence, you see commutativity.